# Abrir AlertDialog em activity atual por uma já finalizada android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Estou fazendo um game, no app assim que perde conexão com a internet ele tem que abrir um AlertDialog na activity atual, mas não estou conseguindo.
O alertDialog abre apenas na activity da qual iniciou o onReceive, no caso a minha **MainActivity**.

Meus códigos:

**MainActivity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        connectivityChangeReceiver = new ConnectivityChangeReceiver();
        registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
        ...
```

***Manifest***

```
...
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
```

***Classe que verifica a conexão***

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public AlertDialog alerta;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            if(isConnected(ctx)){
                //O código aqui é executado ao conectar
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(alerta!=null){
                    alerta.dismiss();
                }
            }else{
                //O código aqui é executado ao desconectar
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View viewCorpo = li.inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);
                View viewTitulo = li.inflate(R.layout.titlealert, null);

                viewCorpo.findViewById(R.id.bt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        alerta.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                builder.setCustomTitle(viewTitulo);
                builder.setView(viewCorpo);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                alerta = builder.create();
                alerta.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Enquanto a aplicação não da um `finish()` na MainActiviy, o AlertDialog é aberto nela, mesmo que a aplicação já esteja em outra activity, caso o `finish()` seja executado na MainActivity e o app tente dar o `show()` no alert o app é fechado, acho muito estranho por conta do Toast aparecer sempre na activity atual e funcionar perfeitamente sendo que o Alert usa o mesmo Context que ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma Activity base para colocar o código do Receive nela, então você vai herdar dela em todas as suas Activity.

BaseActivity

```
  public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          IntentFilter intentFilter = new 
          IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
          connectivityChangeReceiver = new ConnectivityChangeReceiver();
          registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
           ...
```

Outras Activities:

```
public class Activity extends BaseActivity {
```

Comment: Deu certo em partes. O AlertDialog está abrindo na tela atual, independente de qual seja, porém após eu sair da Main e entrar novamente ele da erro no ***show()*** dizendo que foi fechada a activity.
No BaseActivity coloquei extends AppCompatActivity pois uso Fragments no app, isso influência em algo ?
Preciso de algo no Manifest ?

Comment: Provavelmente você esqueceu de desregistrar o broadcast receiver quando a activity é destruída, unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver), você precisa respeitar o lifecycle quando está atualizando a view.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Coloquei o `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)` nos `onStop()`e `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver,Intent filter)` nos `onStart()` das activity, assim respeitando o lifecycle da aplicação.